# Google fonts в IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-fonts

Google шрифты не работают в Internet Explorer. Как быть?

Answer (score 3):

1. Проверить правильность подключения шрифтов.
2. Проверить используемый язык, если на сайте русский, то выбранный шрифт должен поддерживать кириллицу.

p.s: по вашему вопросу сложно понять в чем причина. добавили бы код

Answer (score 3):

```
@font-face {
     font-family:'Hksl';
     src: url('../fonts/Constacia Modern.eot');
     src:url('../fonts/Constacia Modern.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/Constacia Modern.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/Constacia Modern.ttf') format('truetype'), 
     url('../fonts/Constacia Modern.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
}
```

- Выберите нужный шрифт  (шрифт должен поддерживать кириллицу)
- Конвертируйте его во все необходимые форматы
  вот ссылка http://www.font2web.com/
- загрузите на сайт в папку
- подключите в файле css (показано вверху)
- и назначьте на каком элементе их использовать

Вот так:

```
section {
  font-family:'Hksl', serif;
}
```

Удачи, надеюсь помогло (дерзайте)

Answer (score 0):

Решение — использование шрифтов и в формате `.woff`, и в `.eot`, при этом в специфическом порядке. Советую воспользоваться генеротарами на подобии [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).